# Internet connectivity and Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am working on app where I do need to check if Internet connection is stabilized or not. If Internet connection is not stabilized then we need to call our web service else we will not hit that.

For that I wrote following Broadcast receiver in Java since I read that android now want developer to register this receiver in Java class.

so here it is

```
private class NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


           callMyWebService();


    }


 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        if (!isNetworkBroadcastReceiverRegistered) {
            if (NetworkChangeBR == null) {
                NetworkChangeBR = new NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver();
                registerReceiver(NetworkChangeBR, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
                isNetworkBroadcastReceiverRegistered = true;
            }
        }

        acquireWakeLock(mCustomSharedPreferences.getBoolean(CustomSharedPreferences.KEEP_SCREEN_ON_ALL_THE_TIME, false));

    }

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isNetworkBroadcastReceiverRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeBR);
        NetworkChangeBR = null;
        isNetworkBroadcastReceiverRegistered = false;
    }
}
```

**Problems:** **But I face following problems**

- When I first register the receiver in my onResume method, it got automatically fired, which in return calls my webservice where as there is no internet change occur in real
- 2ndly this is only checking the Wireless connection and disconnection, but I want to get callback when wireless is finally connected to internet and when it happens the broadcast must throw callback to my application

Please help me in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your `BroadcastReceiver` is immediately triggered is because the broadcast `Intent` `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` is a "sticky" broadcast. This allows apps to register for and receive immediately the last broadcast event of this type (so that they can determine the current connectivity situation). If this "sticky" broadcast is causing you problems, just check for that in `onReceive()` and ignore it:

```
// Ignore the sticky broadcast of the initial state
if (isInitialStickyBroadcast()) {
    return;
}
```

There is a lot of data passed as "extras" in the `Intent` that your `BroadcastReceiver` gets. You can tell, for example, if the event is a CONNECT or a DISCONNECT event, etc. Check the documenttion on `ConnectivityManager` to determine what "extras" are sent and how to use them.

Comment: what is isInitialStickyBroadcast

Comment: A "sticky" broadcast is a broadcast that stays around in the system after the `BroadcastReceiver`s that are registered for that broadcast are all triggered. This allows the system to keep the "last sent broadcast" of a certain type. This is used to record the current state of something (examples: connectivity, flight mode, battery level, signal strength) so that an app can register to receive changes, and immediately receive a broadcast `Intent` that contains the "current state".